# Problems with uln2803 darlington transistor array

Tags: transistors, darlington

I am using a few ULN2803's to control LED's. The pin connections and circuit that I am using are shown in the figures below.

When a HIGH signal is sent to any of the inputs of the transistor array, all of the LED's switch on, whereas only the one receiving the 5V signal is supposed to be switching to ground.

When there is no HIGH signal to any of the inputs, all LED's are off.

Is there something obvious that I am missing? What would the solution be?

[image: ULN803 Pin connections]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnU4y3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[ULN2803 Datasheet](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=7064&prodName=ULN2803APG)

Comment: Why have you got a 300 ohm resistor in the ground connection?

Comment: To limit the current through the LED(s).

Comment: Have you thought about why that doesn't work when different numbers of LED's are lit?

Answer (score 1):

O1, O2, ... On outputs are open collectors. So, cathode of each LED should be connected to each output. Don't forget to connect the anode of each LED to positive supply line with a series current limiter resistor *(First answer shows how to calculate its value)*. GND should go the negative supply line *(i.e. (-) terminal of battery)* - If you want to measure total load current, you can place a small resistor (say, 1 Ohm) between this pin and negative supply line. COMMON terminal is for protecting the collectors, so you can connect this pin directly to the positive supply line:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwHmHs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also, if you want to drive a single LED for each output, I personally recommend you to use 5V or 9V instead. Because 12V seems to be a bit high.

Comment: So, the question asked was why his circuit does what it does. Sure, making a recommendation is nice but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are raising the common emitter voltage with R1 so that they all turn on.

- To use it properly, ground pin 9 to Vbat- and supply series Current limiting R to each LED { chose on either side}.
- Normally  the supply voltage is only <2V greater than the LED string
- You calculate the V drop on R to limit the current and subtract the Vout(sat) voltage from Vbat @ estimated current.

  - If you use a single LED, then choose 5V

    - and (5-1.2-Vf{led}) / If{led} = R

Comment: How does raising the emitter voltage turn on an NPN transistor?

Comment: good question. ... maybe...thru the parasitic output diodes not intended as conductors. All LEDs on dim.

Comment: I think I will try this. Any specific reason to use separate resistors for each LED besides having a constant current flow that does not depend on the number of active LED's? Asking since space is very limited so adding individual resistors could be quite difficult. I don't mind some fluctuations in brightness.

Comment: What LEd pn and current?

Comment: Also, you are correct that the LED's not intended to switch on are on dim.

Comment: Straight from the supply, before branching to individual LED's.

Comment: What is your LED part number (pn) and desired forward current= If ???

Comment: I have no idea what the pn is or the forward voltage. I will test it now. Desired forward current is 30 - 40mA.

Comment: I can calculate the resistor values required. What I was proposing is essentially the schematic posted by Tyler, and asking if you would consider this a viable alternative to your proposal, which is essentially the same as the schematic drawn by Rohat Kılıç if I understand correctly.

Comment: you can also ignore my advice and questions..... at least attempt to show what the LED looks like and colour

Comment: 3.3V vf measured, its a green 5mm Led. I will assume If=30mA to be on the safe side.

Comment: This is why I asked.... 5mm LEDs are rated for 20mA and thus 12V is wasted on a 3.3V LED.  30mA is ABSOLUTE MAX with no margin, thats why 20mA is speciofied and maybe.. 25 mA  which runs hotter and shorter lifespan.  In fact. at 20mA the ULN driver is over kioll and it can be run off JCxx CMOS 5V drivers using 50 Ohm internal ESR with 2.7V drop/20mA= 135 Ohms now subtract ESR of 74HCxx driver and Rs becomes ~85 Ohms to 5V  . pls give more details on your source and LED in future. ESR is the differential voltage rise over current eg.g VOL/IOL

Comment: direct dirve is only used when driving LEDs at the same rail voltage (5V) from the low side and thus a smaller series R , Rs is needed. Then total power dissipated in source is raised but can be computed within package limits  30mA is only for experimental use.

Comment: I forgot since you dont need the ULN driver, you can drive from High Side from Arduino to Anode +R to gnd.

Answer (score 0):

The positive side of your supply has to go to anode of the leds with a resistor in series. The negative side of your supply to the ground. The common again to the positive side of your supply. Is only for protection against flyback. See the example in the datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this.

First, I would select a LED (for example this one [Datasheet](http://www.cree.com/~/media/Files/Cree/LED%20Components%20and%20Modules/HB/Data%20Sheets/C503B%20BAS%20BAN%20BCS%20BCN%20GAS%20GAN%20GCS%20GCN%201094.pdf)). From this particular datasheet we can see that the typical forward voltage is 3.2 V @ IF 20 mA. (Substitute in your own values as needed.)

Now we need to select a resistor to drop the 12 V supply down to about 3.2V.
$$V = IR$$
$$(12 - 3.2)V = 20mA * R$$
$$R = 440 Ohms$$

Now as a check we should ask how much power will be dissipated in the resistor.
$$P = VI$$
$$P = 8.8V * 20mA$$
$$P = 0.176 watts.$$
So a 440 Ohm 1/4 watt resistor for each LED is required. (440 Ohms is not a standard value so you can use two 220 in series) On a side note, if this is for a home project that shouldn't be a problem, if not you may want to consider lowering the voltage of the Power Supply (Battery) to waste less power.

Putting it all together...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMsFDd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>